# Add file into database (as blob) from node js form

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I wanted to get file from form

```
<form action="/addPage" method="POST">
<h3>Add Page:</h3>
<p>Give icon: <input name='plik' type="file"/></p>
<p>Link: <input name='link' type="text"/></p>
<p>Title: <input name='tytul' type="text"/></p>
<p>Opis: <input name='opis' type='text'/><br><input type="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

I wrote this code to handle it:

```
const [re] = await (global.db).query("INSERT INTO sites VALUES (LOAD_FILE(?), ?, ?, ?);", [req.body.plik, req.body.link,req.body.tytul,req.body.opis]);
```

but I got value null (I know what `req.body.plik` returns sting containing name of file) but how do I get to the file and add it into database. This query puts data properly in database, the only exception is that icon column is null

I'm using node 20.5.2, XAMPP, and mysql2": "^3.6.2"

I want to send blob into database consisting of the file sent

Comment: You should name your columns in an `INSERT` statement, otherwise table schema changes will break your DML and you won't know why.

Comment: Your `<form>` needs `enctype="multipart/form-data"`